# How to host Java based website?

Tags: java, websites, hosting

I am a web developer.  I have developed a website based on Java, Hibernate and Oracle Database Technologies.

I want to host this website on internet. Previously, I use to contact 3rd party organizations to host them on their virtual servers. Now I am looking forward to host it myself. But I have no knowledge.

Please help me on how to host the java based website through my Ubuntu Desktop 13.10.

Answer (score -1):

How can I imagine a "Java based" website ? If there are any .html files you can try

```
apt-get install apache2
```

I hope I could help you

Comment: Java Based Website - Means Websites developed using Java, (Java Server Pages)JSP, Servlets, and Frameworks such as Struts, Spring. I have used Oracle Database as an back-end.
sourceeditlink